# Method in type not applicable, but passing the right number of variables(?)

Tags: java

In lines 41 and 42,

> push(stack,br); and pop(stack);

I am getting the error "Method in type not applicable"
Any ideas what's causing it, and how to avoid doing it in the future? 
Thanks

```
public class Reverse2
{                                                             

  public static void push(Stack<String> stack,BufferedReader br) throws IOException                                 
{

    String line = br.readLine();
    while ( line != null)
        {
    stack.push(line);
    line = br.readLine();
        }

}
  public static void pop(Stack<String> stack)
    {
      while (stack.isEmpty() == false)
      System.out.print(stack.pop());
    }

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException                        
{
   stack stack = new stack();
   Scanner K = new Scanner(System.in);                                          
   String filename;                                                        
   System.out.print("Enter filename ");                                          
   filename = K.next();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
   push(stack,br);
   pop(stack);
   br.close();
}

}
```

Comment: What is this: `stack stack = new stack();`?

Comment: ^whatever it is, it certainly is not a Stack<String> which it needs to be

Comment: The method accepts Stack<String> but you (presumably, I'm not sure how your code even complies) pass a type of stack (not paramerized).

Comment: You not only have to pass in the correct *number* of variables, but also they need to be the correct *type* as specified by the method signature.

Comment: This won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
stack stack = new stack()
```

When it should be:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
```